# Returning response from Dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm implementing login functionality to my application and am trying to return the response from a dispatched thunk action. I'm purposely entering the incorrect password because i'd like for the errors that are set in my backend to display within an antd notification on the frontend. My expected response should be:

```
return res.status(400).json({
    success: false,
    message: 'Invalid email address or password.',
});
```

but instead i'm getting the following in the console:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

**Route:**

```
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  // Validate Login Input
  const { error } = validateLoginInput(req.body);
  if (error)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ success: false, message: error.details[0].message });

  req.body.email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
  req.body = sanitize(req.body);

  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // See if user exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Invalid email address or password.',
      });
    }

    // Compare passwords
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Invalid email address or password.',
      });
    }

    // Return jsonwebtoken
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id,
      },
    };
    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: 3600 },
      (error, token) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json({ token });
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, messsage: 'Server error' });
  }
};
```

**Actions:**

```
export const loginBegin = () => ({
  type: LOGIN_BEGIN,
});

export const loginSuccess = (user) => ({
  type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  payload: user,
});

export const loginFail = (error) => ({
  type: LOGIN_FAIL,
  payload: error,
});
```

**Thunk:**

```
export const attemptLogin = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loginBegin());
  return await postLogin(formData)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      console.log(res.data); <-- This doesn't even show in console
    })
    // .then(() => {
    //   setTimeout(() => {
    //     dispatch(push('/app'));
    //   }, 2000);
    // })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(loginFail(error));
    });
};
```

**onSubmit:**

```
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
  const { email, password } = values;
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    const response = await dispatch(attemptLogin({ email, password }));
    console.log(response); <-- returns undefined

    if (response.data.success) {
      setLoading(false);
      notification['success']({
        message: 'Congrats!',
        description: response.message,
      });
    } else {
      notification['error']({
        message: 'Uh-oh!',
        description: response.message,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not returning the response in the promise. Also, if you are getting a 400 response, it probably rejects the promise or throws an error.

```
export const attemptLogin = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loginBegin());
  return await postLogin(formData)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      return res;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(loginFail(error));
      return error; // this will only work if the error is the response object.
    });
};
```